# How to do a search from a list with non-prefix keywords

Tags: c#, search, autosuggest

I am programming a program to search the name from the list and I need to find them even if the keyword is not in front of the names (that's what I mean non-prefix)

**e.g.** if I my list is the music instruments and I type *"guit"* to the search textbox.
It should find the names *"Guitar, Guitarrón, Acoustic Guitar, Bass Guitar, ..."*
or something like this [Longdo Dictionary's](http://dict.longdo.com) search suggestion.

here is my *simple and stupid* algorithm (that's all I can do)

```
    const int SEARCHROWLIMIT = 30;
    private string[] DoSearch(string Input, string[] ListToSearch)
    {
        List<string> FoundNames = new List<string>();

        int max = 0;
        bool over = false;
        for (int k = 0; !over; k++)
        {
            foreach (string item in ListToSearch)
            {
                max = (max > item.Length) ? max : item.Length;
                if (k > item.Length) continue;
                if (k >= max) { over = true; break; }
                if (!Input.Equals("Search")
                    && item.Substring(k, item.Length - k).StartsWith(Input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    bool exist = false;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!exist && i < FoundNames.Count)
                    {
                        if (item.Equals(FoundNames[i]))
                        {
                            exist = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (!exist && FoundNames.Count < SEARCHROWLIMIT)
                        FoundNames.Add(item);
                    else if (FoundNames.Count >= SEARCHROWLIMIT) over = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return FoundNames.ToArray();
    }
```

I think this algorithm is too slow for a large number of names and after several trial-and-error, I decided to add SEARCHROWLIMIT to breaks the operation
And I also think there're some readymade methods that can do that.

And another problem is I need to search music instruments by a category like *strings, percussions, ...* and by the country of origins. So I need to search them with filter by type and country.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your examples only give cases where the search query is at the beginning of a word. What if it's in the middle of a word, like searching for `xyz` from terms like `abcxyzdef`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LINQ you could write code like this:

```
var resultSet = products

    // filter products by category
    .Where(product => product.Category == "strings")

    // filter products by origin
    .Where(product => product.Origin == "italy")

    // filter products whose name contains a word starting with "guit"
    .Where(product => (" " + product.Name).Contains(" guit"))

    // limit the result set to the first 30 matching products
    .Take(30);
```

If your sets of products is reasonably small, you can use LINQ-to-Objects. Otherwise you should use a database and have a look at LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: Be careful. Apparently reccomending a DB is not appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One word. Database!

Seriously, if you want to do all these different searches, consider placing your data into a database with a schema that simplifies the categorization issues you are having. Sql Server Express now supports [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) which would be very useful for the kind of search you are trying to perform.

There's a nice blog post [here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx) about using FTS with Linq-to-Sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<string> GetItemsWithWordsStartingWithSubstring(List<string> list, string substring)
{
    var query = from str in list
                from item in str.Split(' ')
                where item.StartsWith(substring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                select str;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I hope I have read your intiial question properly. This function will return any item from the list that contains a word starting with your substring. More punctuation could be added to the split parameters. Given a list with the following contents:

> "abcdef","defabc","def abc","xyz"

A search on "abc" will find "abcdef" and "def abc", but not "defabc".

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answers.
now I found the best search without inventing any algorithms.